# How to re-install chocolatey package

Tags: chocolatey

Story is I installed Firefox from choco, then I uninstall it from Program and Features manually. After that I found it still list in choco list --local-only. I cannot run choco install firefox because choco thought it already "exists".

How to update choco list? or anyone know how to re-install it?

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't a tech support site. Try [su].

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can issue a `choco uninstall firefox -y`, then a `choco install firefox` or a forced reinstall via `choco install firefox --force --force-dependencies`